# How would I express this Scheme function more clearly?

Tags: lisp, scheme

```
(define (repeated f n)
   if (= n 0)
   f
   ((compose repeated f) (lambda (x) (- n 1))))
```

I wrote this function, but how would I express this more clearly, using simple recursion with repeated?

I'm sorry, I forgot to define my compose function.

```
(define (compose f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

And the function takes as inputs a procedure that computes f and a positive integer n and returns the procedure that computes the nth repeated application of f.

Comment: Have you tested this function? Does it currently do what you think it should?

Comment: Sorry about not making it clear enough, I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that (repeated f 3) should return a function g(x)=f(f(f(x))). If that's not what you want, please clarify. Anyways, that definition of repeated can be written as follows:

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (lambda (x)
    (if (= n 0)
        x
        ((repeated f (- n 1)) (f x))))) 

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define y (repeated square 3))

(y 2) ; returns 256, which is (square (square (square 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (lambda (x)
    (let recur ((x x) (n n))
      (if (= n 0)
          args
          (recur (f x) (sub1 n))))))
```

Write the function the way you normally would, except that the arguments are passed in two stages. It might be even clearer to define `repeated` this way:

```
(define repeated (lambda (f n) (lambda (x) 
  (define (recur x n)
    (if (= n 0)
        x
        (recur (f x) (sub1 n))))
  (recur x n))))
```

You don't have to use a 'let-loop' this way, and the lambdas make it obvious that you expect your arguments in two stages.
(Note:recur is not built in to Scheme as it is in Clojure, I just like the name)

```
> (define foonly (repeat sub1 10))
> (foonly 11)
1
> (foonly 9)
-1
```

The cool functional feature you want here is currying, not composition. Here's the Haskell with implicit currying:

```
repeated _ 0 x = x
repeated f n x = repeated f (pred n) (f x)
```

I hope this isn't a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

What *is* your function trying to do, just out of curiosity? Is it to run `f`, `n` times? If so, you can do this.

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (for-each (lambda (i) (f)) (iota n)))
```